# Range.to_a example in "Programming Ruby"

Tags: ruby

thanks for checking this question out. This is my first question here so any help/criticism appreciated. I'm working my way (beginner) through the free online version of Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide, version 1. The following example does not do (when I do it) what the book says it should:

```
class VU


  include Comparable


  attr :volume


  def initialize(volume)  # 0..9
    @volume = volume
  end


  def inspect
    '#' * @volume
  end


  # Support for ranges


  def <=>(other)
    self.volume <=> other.volume
  end


  def succ
    raise(IndexError, "Volume too big") if @volume >= 9
    VU.new(@volume.succ)
  end
end
```

Should do the following, according to the book, in irb:

```
medium = VU.new(4)..VU.new(7)
medium.to_a     »   [####, #####, ######, #######]
medium.include?(VU.new(3))  »   false
```

But what does happen for me is medium.to_a returns with an array of the VU objects like so:

```
#<VU:0x9648918>                                                              
#<VU:0x96488b4>                                                              
#<VU:0x964888c>                                                              
#<VU:0x9648878>
```

And that makes sense to me (I think). What doesn't make sense to me is the book's assertion that what should be returned is an array of '#'s. Wouldn't we need to invoke the inspect method in order to get those "#'s?

Thanks!
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you see in irb? `inspect` is called implicitly on return values in irb.  You are correct in that array **is** filled with VU objects, but what should be displayed is the output of `inspect` for those objects.

```
> x = VU.new(5)
=> #####
> x.class
=> VU
> x.succ
=> ######
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I lied, it wasn't in irb after all.  I said that because I believed the behavior running it in irb and the behavior running it as an .rb script in the interpreter (the word interpreter escaped me at the time so I just said irb) would be the same. I now see the truth of it and I will try to be more specific in the future. Thanks again.